# FTP connection via IPAddress

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to open an FTP connection having as parameter the IPAddress and not the url.

here is my code:

the address I'm using is valid and in IExplorer I can access the ftp server, while with my program I enter in the exception with the error invalid URI.

```
 public bool TestConnection(IResult result)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://1.1.1.1");
        if (request == null)
        {
            result.SetError(Translate.InvalidUrl);
            return false;
        }
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

how can I solve this problem? is there a way to open an ftp connection with an IPAddress and not with Url?

thank you in advance

Comment: This code won't compile

Comment: re-edit, now it compiles

Comment: For whatever it's worth, the [offical documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx) is wrong here. It says that passing `ftp://` will return a `FileWebRequest` instead of a `FtpWebRequest`.  But it does do what you'd expect and return the `FtpWebRequest`.

Comment: Sorry I was missing the request.method, now it works

Comment: Add a trailing slash to the url. `"ftp://1.1.1.1/"`